# How to find the return value of last executed command in UNIX?

Tags: unix

How to find the return value of last executed command in UNIX?

Comment: >echo $?
By the way, did u really want to ask this?

Comment: Looks like around 25,000 people wanted to ask this.

Comment: I think the vast majority of users will be interested in how `bash` delivers the return value of the last executed command. But it's worth mentioning that not all shells are the same. I think your question should be more specific.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the shell variable `$?`

Such as:

```
$ true ; echo $?
0
$ false ; echo $?
1
```