# How can I check if PostgreSQL is installed or not via Linux script?

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

I want to check in a script if PostgreSQL is installed or not on Linux and print the result. 
Any suggestions on how to do the check?

Comment: What do you mean by "PostgreSQL is installed"? Pgsql client? Client libraries? Pgsql server?

Comment: See also these generic BASH commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/1736679

Answer (score 138, accepted):

What about trying the `which` command?

If you were to run `which psql` and Postgres is not installed there appears to be no output. You just get the terminal prompt ready to accept another command:

```
> which psql
>
```

But if Postgres is installed you'll get a response with the path to the location of the Postgres install:

```
> which psql
/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/psql
```

Looking at `man which` there also appears to be an option that could help you out:

```
-s      No output, just return 0 if any of the executables are found, or
        1 if none are found.
```

So it seems like as long as whatever scripting language you're using can can execute a terminal command you could send `which -s psql` and use the return value to determine if Postgres is installed. From there you can print that result however you like.

I do have postgres installed on my machine so I run the following

```
> which -s psql
> echo $?
0
```

which tells me that the command returned 0, indicating that the Postgres executable was found on my machine.

[Here's the information about using `echo $?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123650/how-to-find-the-return-value-of-last-executed-command-in-unix)

Comment: The only option `which` has for me is `-a` (print all matching pathnames of each argument), resulting in an illegal option if I use `-s`.

Comment: Hey @Dennis

I'm not sure what your motivations are, but I think in the spirit of my original response, you could probably do something using the -a flag. If there is no output then you can assume it is not installed, and if there is output you know that it is (and where) it's installed because you get the path back.

Let me know if that's helpful or if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: The problem with `which` is that it varies a lot over different operating systems. But you're right that the `-a` flag can be used, you can even use no flag at all: `if which foo >/dev/null; then echo exists; fi`. Another problem is that this will only search your PATH.

Comment: `which psql` will not tell you if the Postgres **server** is installed. It's possible to install the client package (psql) without the server

Answer (score 41):

We can simply write:

```
psql --version
```

output show like:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Comment: Which will only tell you if `psql` is installed, not if the server is installed (and it reports the **psql** version, not the version of a potentially installed server)

Answer (score 10):

If it is debian based.

```
aptitude show postgresql | grep State
```

But I guess you can just try to launch it with some flag like `--version`, that simply prints some info and exits.

**Updated** using "service postgres status". Try:

```
service postgres status
if [ "$?" -gt "0" ]; then
  echo "Not installed".
else
  echo "Intalled"
fi
```

Comment: It's noteworthy that this command would only work on the Debian based family of Linux distros.

Comment: didnt worked ,no command found, i know command `service posrgres status`, but how to check result

Comment: I don't have it installed, so it printed out "posrgres: unrecognized service"

Comment: some systems don't have the `service` command. In Ubuntu or Debian, I'd check for `/etc/init.d/postgres status` or something like that.

Comment: I should point out that if it says "posrgres: unrecognized service" [sic], you might still have "postgres"  installed.  Just sayin', in case somebody copies and pastes.

Answer (score 6):

There is no single simple way to do it, because PostgreSQL might be installed and set up in many different ways:

- Installed from source in a user home directory
- Installed from source into `/opt` or `/usr/local`, manually started or started by an init script
- Installed from distributor `rpm` / `deb` packages and started via init script
- Installed from 3rd party `rpm` / `deb` packages and started via init script
- Installed from packages but *not* set to start
- Client installed, connecting to a server on a different computer
- Installed and running but not on the default `PATH` or default port

You can't rely on `psql` being on the `PATH`. You can't rely on there being only one `psql` on the system (multiple versions might be installed in different ways). You can't do it based on port, as there's no guarantee it's on port 5432, or that there aren't multiple versions.

Prompt the user and ask them.

Answer (score 5):

There is no straightforward way to do this.  All you can do is check with the package manager (rpm, dpkg) or probe some likely locations for the files you want.  Or you could try to connect to a likely port (5432) and see if you get a PostgreSQL protocol response.  But none of this is going to be very robust.  You might want to review your requirements.

Comment: Absolutely right. I have installed my PostgreSQL server from sources, under `teapot` user name and changed binary / service names to `TeaPotSQL`. No other users have permissions to read directory where it is installed. Default port is also changed. Go find it :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you are running Debian Linux (or derivative) and if you have a postive return with `> which psql`, then simply type `psql -V` (capital "V") and you will get a return like: `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.8`

Comment: I presume this only indicates that the psql client exists rather than the server as OP clarified in his comment.  Also the psql client version may mismatch the server version.

Answer (score 4):

And if everything else fails from these great choice of answers, you can always use "find" like this. Or you may need to use sudo

If you are root, just type `$$> find / -name 'postgres'`

If you are a user, you will need sudo priv's to run it through all the directories

I run it this way, from the `/` base to find the whole path that the element is found in. This will return any files or directories with the "postgres" in it.

You could do the same thing looking for the `pg_hba.conf` or `postgresql.conf` files also.

Answer (score 3):

For many years I used the command:

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

On one hand it is useful (for any process) and gives useful info (but from process POV). But on the other hand it is for checking if the server you know, you already installed is running.

At some point I found [this tutorial](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-view-which-postgres-version-is-running/), where the usage of the **locate** command is shown. It looks like this command is much more to the point for this case.

Answer (score 2):

`aptitude show postgresql | grep Version` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Go to bin directory of postgres db such as `/opt/postgresql/bin` & run below command  :

```
[...bin]# ./psql --version

psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.4
```

Here you go . .

Comment: We can simply write:
`psql --version`

output show like:
```psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)```

Answer (score 1):

dpkg -l | grep postgres

RUN the above command and if you get the output as shown in the image then it does not exist on your system

[image: Output of the command]

Source:-[Click here for more info](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-uninstall-postgresql-from-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=Conclusion-,To%20uninstall%20Postgres%20from%20your%20Ubuntu%20operating%20system%2C%20open%20the,%E2%80%9Csudo%20apt%20autoremove%E2%80%9D%20command)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also check in `/opt` mount in following path `/opt/PostgresPlus/9.5AS/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

Well, all answersabove are good but not in all cases.

Basically check the folder `/etc/postgresql/`

in most cases there will be one subfolder eg. `/etc/postgresql/11/` (or `/etc/postgresql/12`) which means that you have installed 11 (or 12) version, however in many cases you may have many of such subfolders, so having them all means that all those versions had been ever installed and  could be in use ... so be aware of this important trace.

ps using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Go window **services** ad search for PostGreSQL.
here I found
[image]