# How to cout the return value of the main function "main()" in c++?

Tags: c++

How to cout the return value of the main function "main()"? I just want to check if the return value of main function is really "0" when it is successfully executed.

Thank you!

Comment: Rename `main()` to `notmain()`. Add a new `main()` function that calls `notmain()`, and prints the value it returns.

Comment: You decide the return value, not the compiler. Also,it is untraditional and uncanny to call `main()`

Comment: `echo $?` from the shell usually serves you well

Comment: That's platform specific. The C++ Standard doesn't describe a Universe outside of C++ (or main). Besides, returning 0 on success is a **convention**. Not everyone likes that convention.

Comment: Send the value to `cout` before you return? How is this even a question, really?

Comment: @MrEricSir: How does that verify which value is passed to the OS?

Comment: The same way you cout other variables? You are always responsible for what main returns. You modify the return value according to what happens in your program.

Comment: If I rename main() to notmain() which is a normal function, I know how to print its return value. I tried to cout the main, but it returned the result of the function called in the main the first time. And the second time I tried, it directly became an error... But thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to test that the following returns 0?

```
int main() {
  int rc = doSomething();
  return rc;
}
```

You can do it like this:

```
int main() {
  int rc = doSomething();
  std::cout << rc << "\n";  // Just print it out before returning
  return rc;
}
```

But it's better to check the return value in the *shell* from where you run your application:

**On UNIX/Linux (in shell):**

```
 > ./my_app
 > echo $?
 0
```

**On Windows (in command prompt):**

```
> my_app.exe
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Note that in C++ you are not allowed to intercept the call to `main()` or call it yourself.

**3.6.1 Main function**

> The function `main` shall not be used within a program.

So you should not attempt to wrap the `main()` call and print its return value. Even if that works, it would not be portable (not to mention you'd actually end up running your application twice).

Comment: "So what you want is impossible" `std::cout << the_return_value; return the_return_value;`.

Comment: "In C++ you can't intercept the call to main() or call it yourself." no you can do that , see my code in my answer

Comment: No, I don't mean to print out the result of the function inside a main(). Every main() returns a zero at the end, if it is successfully run. I want to print out this returned value "0".

Comment: @HassenDhia: There are lots of things you can do. Some of them are well defined, others are undefined. Calling `main` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unix command to check the return value of the previously executed command, in this case your c program.

```
echo $?
```

The shell variable $? is the return code of the previous command.

[How to find the return value of last executed command in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123650/how-to-find-the-return-value-of-last-executed-command-in-unix)

If you want to check the value within the code, just cout the value right before the return.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is special, mostly because you can't call it yourself. The value that it returns is passed back to the operating system, which does whatever is appropriate. The C++ standard can't dictate how the OS treats various return values, so it provides an abstraction: you can use `return EXIT_SUCCESS` to indicate success, and you can use `return EXIT_FAILURE` to indicate failure. (You can also use `return 0` to mean `return EXIT_SUCCESS`; the program's runtime system has to handle this correctly). The values of the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are suitable for the OS that the program was compiled for. While `0` is the typical value for `EXIT_SUCCESS`, it's certainly possible for an OS to require a different value, and `EXIT_SUCCESS` will have the appropriate value for that OS. So even if you could check the value returned from `main` it wouldn't tell you much, without also knowing what value the OS expects from a successful program.

Answer (score 0):

Type the other function after `main()`, then type `main();` in that function
One problem though, main will be the first function to be called automatically. Although, i'm sure there is a way to fix it. This is how you call main or return main.
Hope this helps.

```
int main() {

int i = 5;
cout << i;
}

int second() {
 main();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

If it's 0, then it's 0. You are the one who specify the return value of *your own* function. If you are unsure, please add code and/or problem, which is bothering you.